# Managing systemd timers triggering conflicting oneshot services

Tags: systemd

I'm working on creating services that can do a logical MySQL backup as well as a physical MySQL backup. The logical backups would be done every 4 hours while the physical backups would be done once a day at a specific time. Both rely on shutting down the MySQL slave which the backup is based on. They also need to handle not running concurrently. In addition, when boots/reboots, these should not be run not the first invocation.

Logical backup is using `mysqldump` and then uploading to S3.
Physical backup is taking a snapshot of the EBS.

I've been running a simple stress case version where both fire at an interval of 1 minute. The database is empty and small. The EBS Volume is 1GiB. Both can be done in less than one minute.

I use a timer service to trigger the oneshot. I have also made each timer a `Conflicts` to each other as well as restating the timer in `ExecStopPost`.

An example of the service file looks like. Each one references the other

```
[Unit]
After=mysql-slave.service
Conflicts=other-backup-type.timer

[Service]
Type=oneshot
# Just arbitrary name for this example
ExecStart=do_backup.sh
ExecStopPost=/bin/systemctl start other-backup-type.timer
```

What I have seen via `systemctl list-timers` is that both timers are in sync. When both hit 0, one will trigger. What I have found is that once done, the other is will not be triggered. It seems that in this case, the timer is indeed stopped, but the trigger for the other oneshot never is made.

Is there a way to properly handle this without having to offset time? I have found if I make the time period offset slightly it works (seconds cannot be a factor of 60). I'm checking to see if there is a better/more elegant way of supporting this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is the 100% correct answer. I've run through a lot of permutations and based on this, I've come up with this.

Observationally, it seems that if I have 2 timers (A and B) which are setup as `Conflicts=` and also have a collision on expiration with another timer (eg. both setup to trigger every minute), then the one that triggers (let's say it's A) first stops the other and then triggers it's service. However this stop causes the would be trigger on timer B's service to be lost. I'm guessing that the trigger is pulled off some queue and ends up getting tossed in the process of the stop.

Comment: This seems to be what the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Conflicts=) is saying also.